# How to generate graph image from DOT code in python?

Tags: python, dot

Is there any python library which is able to generate an image (no matter which format) from DOT code ?

Something like that:

```
import magic_library
dot_txt = 'digraph G {\n    start -> end;\n}'
magic_library.generateImage(code = dot_txt, file=f.png)
```

I didn't find anything

EDIT 1: This works but I have to create a file.

```
import os
import pydot

s = 'digraph G {\n    start -> end;\n}'

text_file = open("f.dot", "w")
text_file.write(s)
text_file.close()

(graph,) = pydot.graph_from_dot_file('f.dot')
graph.write_png('f.png')

os.remove("f.dot")
```

EDIT 2: The [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57262790/1965878) works perfectly (and is straightforward, not like my previous code)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting dot to png in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5316206/converting-dot-to-png-in-python)

Comment: Note that according to [the on-topic rules](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam". That being said, [`graphviz`](https://pypi.org/project/graphviz/) is probably what you're looking for.

Comment: @JustinEzequiel I don't know if it is really the same question since I try to do it directly from a String, without passing by a file. However, as you can see it in my answer, I didn't find a way to do it without creating a file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [docs](https://pydotplus.readthedocs.io/reference.html#pydotplus.graphviz.graph_from_dot_data), you should be able to use `graph_from_dot_data`:

```
import pydot
dot_txt = 'digraph G {\n    start -> end;\n}'
graph, = pydot.graph_from_dot_data(dot_txt)
graph.write_png('f.png')
```