# Plot model with model_to_dot() in Tensorflow Keras not working

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to plot my model with the `tf.keras.utils.model_to_dot()` function but keep getting the following error:

```
TypeError: object of type 'Cluster' has no len()
```

Here is the code I use:

```
import tensorflow
import pydot

model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
  tf.keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(28, 28, 1)),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(128,activation='relu'),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax')
])

model_graph = tf.keras.utils.model_to_dot(model, expand_nested=True, subgraph=True)
graph = pydot.graph_from_dot_data(model_graph)
graph.write_png('model.png')
```

What do I do wrong here?

Comment: There is a typo: `model_graph = tf.keras.utils.model_to_dot(mode, expand_nested=True, subgraph=True)`; It has to be: `model_graph = tf.keras.utils.model_to_dot(model, expand_nested=True, subgraph=True)` ; parameter passed to `model_to_dot` has to be `model` and not `mode`

Comment: @AshwinGeetD'Sa Thanks! I removed the typo.

Comment: Does it still produce the same error?

Comment: @AshwinGeetD'Sa Yes. That was not the problem. But thanks for pointing it out!

Answer (score 0):

Following the documentation, here https://pydotplus.readthedocs.io/reference.html .

```
pydotplus.graphviz.graph_from_dot_data(data)[source]
Load graph as defined by data in DOT format.

The data is assumed to be in DOT format. It will be parsed and a Dot class will be returned, representing the graph.
```

You're code should be something like this,

```
import pydot

(graph,) = pydot.graph_from_dot_file('somefile.dot')
graph.write_png('somefile.png')
```

Thanks to @Judge Maygarden, [Converting dot to png in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5316206/converting-dot-to-png-in-python) .

Basically, it's expecting a .dot file, not the model itself.

Maybe you're looking for `tf.keras.utils.plot_model`? For example, from https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/utils/plot_model,

```
tf.keras.utils.plot_model(
    model, to_file='model.png', show_shapes=False, show_layer_names=True,
    rankdir='TB', expand_nested=False, dpi=96
)
```

Comment: I don't want to use `tf.keras.utils.plot_model()`. Can you provide a minimal working example that works with a Keras model? I tried to use `pydot` without success.